# Animar um script que troca o src das imagens

Tags: javascript, html5, javascript-eventos

A minha duvida é a seguinte: eu possuo em meu código 2 funções JS que são chamadas com ***onmouseenter*** e ***onmouseout*** em meu codigo HTML, que são elas:

```
function passo1() {       
      document.getElementById("imagem").src="imagens/002.png";
  }
function passo2() {
      document.getElementById("imagem").src="imagens/001.png";
  }
```

O evento de mouseenter muda a imagem para de 001.png para a 002.png (na função **passo1**), enquanto o evento de mouseout muda  a imagem de 002.png para 001.png (na função **passo2**), isso que eu descrivi já está funcionando e as imagens trocam ao passar e tirar o mouse, o problema é que fica algo ***"seco"***, nem tem nenhuma animação, eu queria saber se seria possivel adicionar algum tipo de animação ou transição para esses 2 imagens.

Comment: Cara muito provavelmente isso que vc está tentando fazer daria para fazer facilmente com CSS... já pensou nisso ou tem que ser com JS mesmo?

Comment: Mas é possível por CSS trocar o src de uma imagem? porque ela não está como background de um elemento (se fosse isso, sei que seria possível colocar um hover e trocar o background), ela é o elemento <img>

Comment: Tem várias opções, vc pode ter 2 imagens ao mesmo tempo uma encima da outra, o que seria o MAIS indicado, pois quando vc muda o src, vc vai ter que carregar a outra imagem, e isso pode fazer a imagem "piscar" na tela por um momento, pois vai ficar em branco enquanto carrega a a imagem nova. Tendo as duas uma encima da outra vc não teria problema. A outra opção, mais complexa um pouco é tem um elementos com dois backgrounds-image, um url() para cada imagem. Acredito não ser possível fazer "transição suave" de src, mesmo com JS

Comment: Gostei da ideia de ter uma por cima da outra, poderia deixar uma com z-index maior e ao ter o hover o z-index iria diminuir, mostrando a outra imagem, mas para que elas fiquem uma por cima da outra seria necessário mexer com position, além do top e left.

Comment: Sim teria que usar position, e vc na verdade apenas deixaria a imagem de cima com opacity:0; não precisa de z-index. Mas tudo depende do efeito que vc quer, se quiser que no hover uma imagem saia pela direita e outra entre pela esquerda não vai precisar de position, vc poderia usar margin, então tudo depende do que vc realmente quer... Só acho pouso provável que vc consiga fazer uma transição de SRC, além do problema do carregamento que te falei...

Comment: Entendi, mas obrigado, de verdade, deu pra ter uma boa ideia do que fazer.

Answer (score 1):

Porque não fazer isso com CSS somente? Abaixo segue a forma de fazer com os dois modos (com e sem javascript).

```js
var ctImg = document.querySelector('.ct-imagem#com-js');

ctImg.onmouseenter = () => {
  ctImg.querySelector('.img.frente').style.opacity = '0';
  ctImg.querySelector('.img.tras').style.opacity = '1';
};

ctImg.onmouseout = () => {
  ctImg.querySelector('.img.frente').style.opacity = '1';
  ctImg.querySelector('.img.tras').style.opacity = '0';
};
```

```css
.ct-imagem {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ct-imagem .img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
}

.ct-imagem .img.frente {
  z-index: 2;
}

.ct-imagem .img.tras {
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
}

.ct-imagem#sem-js:hover .img.frente {
  opacity: 0;
}

.ct-imagem#sem-js:hover .img.tras {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<h1>Sem javascript/CSS</h1>
<div class="ct-imagem" id="sem-js">
  <img class="img frente" src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp4302732.jpg">
  <img class="img tras" src="https://www.iwantwallpaper.co.uk/images/muriva-quadra-stone-cube-pattern-wallpaper-3d-effect-square-textured-vinyl-l50501-p5056-13928_image.jpg">
</div>
<h1>Com javascript</h1>
<div class="ct-imagem" id="com-js">
  <img class="img frente" src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp4302732.jpg">
  <img class="img tras" src="https://www.iwantwallpaper.co.uk/images/muriva-quadra-stone-cube-pattern-wallpaper-3d-effect-square-textured-vinyl-l50501-p5056-13928_image.jpg">
</div>
```